# Md-content's width is not 100% in app in cordova

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, cordova, angular-material

I use angular(v1.3.6) and angular-material (v0.10.1). I have a md-content which has simply two input fields and a button. md-content has width of 100%. In the mobile simulator of chrome it is seen as follows:

[image]

but when i compile and run it in genymotion, i take the following result:

[image]

Is that because of a bug in angular-material or is my css normally ignored?

EDIT:

HTML-side

```
<md-content id="login-pane" ng-show="login.status!='ok'">
            <md-input-container>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input ng-model="user.name">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input ng-model="user.pw">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-checkbox ng-model="user.saveInfoToStorage">
            Remember me
            </md-checkbox>
 </md-content>
```

CSS:

```
  #login-pane{
     width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: its not just width, your floating titles as well look different.

Comment: question updated with codes

Comment: #login-pane input{ width:100%;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#login-pane{
     width: 100%;
     display:block;
     float:left;
  }
#login-pane input{
   width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: do you also have an idea why the labels are standing on top (which should actually go to top when they take the focus)

Comment: good workaround. but it would be though useful to keep the label while filling in the field

Answer (score 0):

Set with float property.

```css
#login-pane{
     width: 100%;
     display:block;
     float:left;
  }
```